# AngularJS - Dropdown shows empty field as selected choice when reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've got this dropdown in `AngularJS` and when I first load the page it selects the first item as the default one, which is should. Then when I reload the page the default item is now an empty field. When checking the web console I can see that the selected item has value, but it's not showing in the dropdown. How can this be?

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <h4>{{ dropdown.name }}</h4>
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in dropdown.items"
            ng-change="change(dropdown)"
            ng-model="dropdown.selected"
            ng-init="defaultSelected(dropdown)">
    </select>
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
angular.module('SimPlannerApp')
.controller('dropdownController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.defaultSelected = function(dropdown){
        if(dropdown.selected === undefined){
            dropdown.selected = dropdown.items[0];
        }

        return dropdown.selected;
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

As requested here are the full HTML page along with its controller

```
<link type="text/css" href="app/modules/functions/dropdown/dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row dropdown-container" ng-controller="dropdownController">
    <div ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdowns track by $index" ng-include="'dropdown.html'"></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- Template used for repeating HTML -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dropdown.html">
    <div>
        <h4>{{ dropdown.name }}</h4>
        <select class="form-control"
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in dropdown.items"
            ng-change="change(dropdown)"
            ng-model="dropdown.selected"
            ng-init="defaultSelected(dropdown)">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="dropdown in dropdown.nested track by $index" ng-include="'dropdown.html'"></div>
</script>
```

```
angular.module('SimPlannerApp')
.controller('dropdownController', function ($scope, $q, viewService, socketService, Account, storedProcedureService, popService, sharedService) {
    console.warn('LOADING: dropdown.controller.js');
    viewService.setParameters({ qryusr: Account.get().login }, 'parameters');
    initalize();

    $scope.change = function(dropdown){
        if(dropdown.nested){
            updateNested(dropdown);
        } else {
            lastInLine(dropdown);
        }
    };

    $scope.defaultSelected = function(dropdown){
        setSelected(dropdown);

        return dropdown.selected;
    };

    function setSelected(dropdown){
        console.info('dropdown.selected : ', dropdown.selected);

        if(dropdown.selected === undefined){
            dropdown.selected = dropdown.items[0];
        }

        return dropdown;
    };

    function initalize(){
        var masters = $scope.functions.dropdown;    //  $scope found in parent Controller.
        $scope.dropdowns = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < masters.length; i++){
            createDropdown(masters[i], true);
        }
    };

    function lastInLine(dropdown){
        setParams(dropdown);

        setSelected(dropdown);

        viewService.get();
    };

    function updateNested(parent){
        if(parent.nested){
            for(var i = 0; i < parent.nested.length; i++){
                var nested = parent.nested[i];

                setParams(nested, parent);

                createDropdown(nested, false);
            }
        }
    };

    function setParams(dropdown, parent){
        if(dropdown.populate.params){
            var params = dropdown.populate.params;
            for(var key in params){
                var keyValue = sharedService.camelcase(params[key]);

                if((parent) && (parent.selected[keyValue])){
                    viewService.setParameters({ [key]: parent.selected[keyValue] }, 'parameters');
                } else if ((dropdown.selected) && (dropdown.selected[keyValue])){
                    viewService.setParameters({ [key]: dropdown.selected[keyValue] }, 'parameters');
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function createDropdown(dropdown, isMaster){
        var populate = dropdown.populate,
            storedProcedure = storedProcedureService.getParam(populate.storedProcedure),
            view = $scope.view; //  $scope found in parent Controller.

        socketService.connect(storedProcedure.name, storedProcedure.verb, view)
            .then(function(response){
                dropdown.items = setItems(response, populate.itemFieldName);

                setSelected(dropdown);

                setParams(dropdown);

                updateNested(dropdown);

                if(isMaster){
                    $scope.dropdowns.push(dropdown);
                }

                if(dropdown.nested === undefined){
                    lastInLine(dropdown);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error.message, '\ndata : ', error.data);
                popService.set('Connection failed.');
            });
    };

    function setItems(items, fieldName){
        fieldName = sharedService.camelcase(fieldName);
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            items[i].name = items[i][fieldName];
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

Comment: you can do : ng-init = dropdown.selected = dromdown.items[0]. Note that if you load your items asynchronously this may not work. I don't approve existing answers since they're just static code, to get why your code is not working we need to see how you use the dropDown controller and how you build you're dropdown.items fields

Comment: @Walfrat: You're right, I am loading the dropdowns asynchronously. I've just added the full HTML and controller in order for you to see what I'm doing

Comment: Then the answer is easy : ng-init does not work with asynchronous loading. Just set it programmatically when you're data are ready. This can be either a race problem, or because off your recursive including of template because it will generate the same number of [select] élément that the number of level and they will all point to the same variable : dropdown.selected, and the ng-init would execute for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a standard use of ngInit. I'm surprised that works at all.

As the documentation says, the ngInit directive is used to evaluate an expression in the current scope. What you're doing is calling a function, which not what it's intended for.

Here's the doco: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

You'd be better off just removing the ngInit entirely and simplifying your controller.

Here's a live working example:

```js
angular.module('SimPlannerApp', [])
  .controller('dropdownController', function($scope) {
    $scope.dropdown = {};
    $scope.dropdown.items = [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}];
    $scope.dropdown.name = "Dropdown";

    if (!$scope.dropdown.selected) {
      $scope.dropdown.selected = $scope.dropdown.items[0];
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="SimPlannerApp">
  <div ng-controller="dropdownController">
    <h4>{{ dropdown.name }}</h4>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item as item.name for item in dropdown.items" ng-change="change(dropdown)" ng-model="dropdown.selected">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello i' ve made a jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/106ps0cf/1/

I use an init function to give a default value to the ng-model.

**controller snippet:**

```
 $scope.initialize = function(){
        $scope.dropdown.selected = $scope.dropdown.items[0];//initialize the selected value
   };

   $scope.dropdown = {
   name:'myname',
   items:[{name:'first'},{name:'second'},{name:'third'}],
   selected:null
   };

   $scope.initialize();

   $scope.change = function(){
        console.log('option changed');
   };
```

Hope helps, good luck.